# How to create a trigger on create or update to insert a new row in another (history) table and return its id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, `Asset` (Id, AssetName, etc) and `History.Asset` (HistoryId, HistoryAction, Id, etc).

I want to create a trigger such that whenever I insert or delete or update `Asset` table, it inserts a new row into the `History.Asset` table and returns the `HistoryId`. What's the best way to do so? Or is it impossible for a trigger?

After updating the `Asset` table, I don't want to go back to `History.Asset` table to check what its `HistoryId` is, I want to get back `HistoryId` that was inserted from trigger when I update the `Asset` table

Update:
The bigger problem is that we want to notify user about some (serious not all) changes in the Asset (owner changed, manager changed, asset name changed, etc) for that we use `Issue` table (Id ,Asset_Id, IssueType_Id, Resolved, History_Id) and to make entry to `Issue` table I need HistoryId
(The tables were not planned this way from the very beginning it's just one of the newer requirements from some of the users)

Comment: Why not just use a temporal table?

Comment: We want to keep the history of all the actions taken on Asset table in the History table and I need that HistoryId to perform some other operations on it

Comment: if i remember correctly, triggers shouldn't return resultsets, but i think SCOPE_IDENTITY() should be able to return the value after your update/delete, unless you have multiple triggers that inserts things.

Comment: Well, returning data from a `TRIGGER` is a deprecated feature, so the short answer is that you *can* but the feature may break in a future version when the functionality is removed.

Comment: Using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would likely result in a query than *assumes* the DML operation effects 1 row though, @siggemannen , but we all know that a DML operation can affect 0+ rows. :)

Comment: I still think you should use Temporal Tables. But in your intended setup, why use a trigger, why not just insert into the history table using your procedure? Either way, sounds like you want the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: @ThomA that's true. Sounds like OP assumes that as well. I'm not even sure why he wants to get the historyId, usually log is just for... logging and not further processing

Comment: @siggemannen we want HistoryId to notify a user about the issues if there's any in the Asset, so that user goes to issues page and sees when what kind of issue happened on that particular asset, ex. owner of that asset has changed etc.

Comment: This is now strongly smelling of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). What is the problem you're trying to solve here exactly?

Comment: But don't you want all history assets to display for a specific Asset. So you can anyway just do a select * from historyasset where assetId = CurrentDisplayedAssetID

Comment: @ThomA might be, this is what I understood from my manager: we want to notify user about some serious changes in the Asset (Owner, Manager, AssetName, etc any of those changes) to notify the user taht we have issue with the asset, for that we use Issue table (Id ,Asset_Id, IssueType_Id, Resolved, History_Id) so that's why I need HistoryId

Comment: That sounds like an overly vague requirement that doesn't really explain the need.

Comment: @ThomA yes I think so too, some of the clients asked that from manager

Comment: Sounds like you should modify the trigger that inserts into `History` to also insert into `Issue`, possibly using an `OUTPUT inserted.histpry_id` clause. Do not return data from triggers, it's a deprecated feature and will probably be removed at some point. Without seeing your existing trigger and the full table definitions it's hard to advise.